# what is the difference between easy_install and apt-get

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, package

I have just started using Ubuntu as my first Linux, have a couple of question.

1. What is the difference between easy_install and apt-get?
2. How do I update my packages with packages installed in both these ways?
3. They are under pythonpath right?

Comment: Off topic here, belongs to the [Ubuntu forum](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing two completely separate things.

Aptitude, of which `apt_get` is one part, is the Ubuntu system-wide package manager. It has packages for absolutely everything - applications, libraries, system utils, whatever. They may not be the latest versions, as packages are usually only updated for each separate Ubuntu release (except for security and bug fixes).

`easy_install` is a Python-only system for install Python libraries. It doesn't do anything else. The libraries are installed in the system Python's `site-packages` directory. There are some downsides to easy_install, one of which is that it's hard to upgrade and uninstall libraries. Use `pip` instead.

Comment: very clear .xplanation. thank you